# How to reconnect to RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

My python script constantly has to send messages to RabbitMQ once it receives one from another data source. The frequency in which the python script sends them can vary, say, 1 minute - 30 minutes.

Here's how I establish a connection to RabbitMQ:

```
  rabt_conn = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters("some_host"))
  channel = rbt_conn.channel()
```

I just got an exception

```
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

How can I reconnect to it? What's the best way? Is there any "strategy"? Is there an ability to send pings to keep a connection alive or set timeout?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try gearman module, check this http://gearmanhq.com/help/tutorials/Python/basic/. for creating client and worker connection. here your python script will be client and rabbitmq will be worker

Comment: @PrashantPuri, I don't want to use any api for such dead simple task!

Comment: @PrashantPuri, do you use a web service api to open a terminal? or to reboot your computer?

Comment: its not api, it is generic application framework, that allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages.

Comment: @PrashantPuri, do you use a framework to add 2 and 2? or do you just call +?

Answer (score 23):

RabbitMQ uses *heartbeats* to detect and close "dead" connections and to prevent network devices (firewalls etc.) from terminating "idle" connections. From version 3.5.5 on, the default timeout is set to 60 seconds (previously it was ~10 minutes). From the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html):

> Heartbeat frames are sent about every timeout / 2 seconds. After two missed heartbeats, the peer is considered to be unreachable.

The problem with Pika's *BlockingConnection* is that it is unable to respond to heartbeats until some API call is made (for example, `channel.basic_publish()`, `connection.sleep()`, etc).

The approaches I found so far:

### Increase or deactivate the timeout

RabbitMQ negotiates the timeout with the client when establishing the connection. In theory, it should be possible to override the server default value with a bigger one using the `heartbeat_interval` argument, but the current Pika version (0.10.0) uses the *min* value between those offered by the server and the client. This issue is fixed on current [master](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/665).

On the other hand, is possible to deactivate the heartbeat functionality completely by setting the `heartbeat_interval` argument to `0`, which may well drive you into new issues (firewalls dropping connections, etc)

### Reconnecting

Expanding on @itsafire's answer, you can write your own *publisher* class, letting you reconnect when required. An example naive implementation:

```
import logging
import json
import pika

class Publisher:
    EXCHANGE='my_exchange'
    TYPE='topic'
    ROUTING_KEY = 'some_routing_key'

    def __init__(self, host, virtual_host, username, password):
        self._params = pika.connection.ConnectionParameters(
            host=host,
            virtual_host=virtual_host,
            credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials(username, password))
        self._conn = None
        self._channel = None

    def connect(self):
        if not self._conn or self._conn.is_closed:
            self._conn = pika.BlockingConnection(self._params)
            self._channel = self._conn.channel()
            self._channel.exchange_declare(exchange=self.EXCHANGE,
                                           type=self.TYPE)

    def _publish(self, msg):
        self._channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.EXCHANGE,
                                    routing_key=self.ROUTING_KEY,
                                    body=json.dumps(msg).encode())
        logging.debug('message sent: %s', msg)

    def publish(self, msg):
        """Publish msg, reconnecting if necessary."""

        try:
            self._publish(msg)
        except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
            logging.debug('reconnecting to queue')
            self.connect()
            self._publish(msg)

    def close(self):
        if self._conn and self._conn.is_open:
            logging.debug('closing queue connection')
            self._conn.close()
```

### Other possibilities

Other possibilities which I yet didn't explore:

- [Using an asynchronous adapter for publishing](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/comparing_publishing_sync_async.html)
- Keeping your RabbitMQ connection and your "publish" code on a background thread, which calls periodically `connection.sleep()` to responde to server heartbeats.

Answer (score 8):

Dead simple: some pattern like this.

```
import time

while True:
    try:
        communication_handles = connect_pika()
        do_your_stuff(communication_handles)
    except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        print 'oops. lost connection. trying to reconnect.'
        # avoid rapid reconnection on longer RMQ server outage
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

You will probably have to re-factor your code, but basically it is about catching the exception, mitigate the problem and continue doing your stuff.
The `communication_handles` contain all the pika elements like channels, queues and whatever that your stuff needs to communicate with RabbitMQ via pika.

Comment: Fine, but this solution will go into a maximum recursion depth in case the server will go away for a longer time.

Comment: Granted. This is just a pointer of how to handle a disconnect. I added an optional advice how to handle langer server outages. A grace counter could be added as well, to eventually exit if too many re-connection attempts have been made. Knock yourself out.

Comment: Could use in combination with https://pypi.org/project/retrying/ to retry N times before giving up, to avoid infinite reconnect attempts/retries/recursions etc.